# SQL Query MAX(count(*))

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get `IdPasajero` and the maximum number of tickets purchased from the list of a `Boletos` table that has the record of all tickets purchased by `IdPasajero`.

any ideas?

My Thoughts:

```
SELECT MAX(contador) FROM (
    SELECT IdPasajero, count(idPasajero) contador 
    FROM Boleto
    GROUP BY IdPasajero
) T;
```

This returns only the maximum amount purchased by a passenger or "IdPasajero"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) IdPasajero, count(idPasajero) as contador
FROM Boleto
GROUP BY IdPasajero
ORDER BY contador DESC;
```

If you want all values in the case of ties, use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`.

Comment: But if there are two passengers with the same amount of tickets purchased?

Comment: Gordon answered that with `TOP (1) WITH TIES`

Comment: Oh sorry, Perfect It Works!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
with NbID as (
SELECT IdPasajero, count(IdPasajero) as Nb 
FROM Boleto
group by IdPasajero
),

Maxi as (
select max(Nb) from MaxiID
)
select NbID.* from NbID inner join Maxi on NbID.Nb=Maxi.MaxiID
```